# Cannot resolve method 'super()' error in android studio

Tags: android

I am getting the error: "Cannot resolve method 'super()'" in my code and I am not sure how to resolve this, do you have any clues?

The code is as follows:

```
public GeoView( double left, double top, double width )
{
    super();

    this.left = left;
    this.top = top;
    this.width = width;

    this.transform = null;
    this.backing_store = null;

    this.sink = false;

    this.last_size = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200 );
    this.do_tracking = false;

    Drawable background = new Drawable() {
        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        }

        @Override
        public void setAlpha(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getOpacity() {
            return 0;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Show the enclosing class please.

Comment: Please share the details of the enclosing class to know what the class entends

Comment: Show the inheritance pls, otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is GeoView class? You extended it from another class?
If yes. Check that parent class have empty constructor, because you call it.
If it's your own class and it didn't extended from any other class. Then you don't need to call `super()`.

View doesn't have empty constructor.
You should Have at least one of this constructor.

```
    public GeoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GeoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public GeoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
```

If you want to create view by yourself, you need first constructor. Then you have to

```
GeoView geoView = new GeoView(YourActivity.this);
```

Or you can simply add your view to layout. Then You second will be called constructor. I think you should add all of them.

```
<com.example.yourapp.GeoView
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: It is extended from class View.

Comment: Thank you for that, it worked!  I have a class MapViewer that extends GeoView and I've altered the constructor to include context, however, how or where do I create a Context object when I create a MapViewer object?  Is it ok to type: Context contextObj = new Context(); and pass contextObj into the MapViewer call?

Comment: No Context is your activity. new GeoMap(YourActivity.this);

Comment: Added some details

Comment: Thank you @thealexsandr!